# Firewall to block traffic to specific websites

Tags: firewall, little-snitch

I have recently switched from MAC to Windows Vista. I used to have LittleSnitch on Mac where I can create filters and disable browsing to other websites. I mean, I can create filters so that LittleSnitch will not send traffic to specific websites like Google Analytics etc.

However, I cannot find a similar software on Windows. I tried Zone Alarm firewall, but it doesn't let you add filters to stop traffic to specific websites.

Are there any software available on windows which are similar to LittleSnitch?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Agnitum Outpost](http://www.agnitum.com/). There are WebControl section in settings where you can tune interaction with specific websites.

Comment: I tried Zone Alarm on my Windows 7 PC and it messed up with my Internet Connection Sharing. I have ICS to share Internet connection to my other Windows 7 machine. Now, I am thinking of buying Agnitum Outpost Security Suite and wondering if it poses the same problem to me.. Does any one here have any experience using ICS with Agnitum Outpost firewall installed in their machines?

Comment: I'm not using ICS. But outpost has 30-day trial, so you can check and buy if you'll be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I like Kaspersky Internet Security for Windows, it lets me block by profile, giving some users full access, and others limited access, has a nice built in filter and you can modify this. I set it up on my home computer for the kids in about 5 minutes, including setting up the Windows User for them.

Answer (score 1):

If it's specific tracking websites, you may want to look at Ghostery.  There are Ghostery plugins for [Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9609/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij) and IE as well.

You can also try Adblock which runs on [Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1865) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) as well.  You can list all elements on a page, and block any element specifically, or by simple expressions.

Obviously this only works on users that install these plugins.  I do realize that this isn't as good or universal as what LittleSnitch does, but I hate adding really low level things that affect TCP/IP.